# Different action for unity launcher icon depending on action?

Tags: 11.04, command-line, launcher, chromium

I'm making a launcher that when clicked will open up a chromium window with tabs for Gmail, Google Docs, and Google Calendar, but I'd also like to drag and drop documents into the launcher icon and have them automatically uploaded to Google Docs.

How can I differentiate an Exec for clicking and an Exec for drag and drop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! The Exec command in the Gdocs.Desktop was DocsHelper.sh I opened that up and the penultimate line of code is what command should be executed if no file is present.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst not quite the launcher you would like to make - [WebUp8](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/06/unity-launcher-to-upload-files-to.html) have recently blogged about the following GoogleDocs launcher that does a upload when you drag-and-drop.

[image]

Hope this gives you a few ideas for your final solution.

Comment: That's actually the base of what I'm trying to make... I have the .desktop file from that launcher, but I want to know if I can add a click-only Exec command on top of the drag and drop command